# References on statemachine optimization and code generation?

Tags: c++, optimization, code-generation, language-design, state-machine

As a follow-up to my [state machines as a C++-like language extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852302/a-proposal-to-add-statemachine-support-to-c-like-language) question, I'd like some more help.

My compiler has been extended to parse my state machine extensions and now I'm beginning semantic analysis and code generation. There is a description [on this page](http://ellcc.org/wiki/index.php/State_machines_and_Active_Classes).

Can anyone point me to good references on state machine optimization and code generation?

---

Edit:

I still haven't found any specific references, but this is an interesting project that I didn't know about: http://echarts.org/

They are doing, in a Java syntax, something very similar to what I'm trying to do. Apparently this project originated at AT&T:  http://www.research.att.com/software_tools

Comment: My eyes! The goggles, they do nothing!

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647631/c-state-machine-design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a good chapter or two on state machines in Allen Hollub's book "Compiler Design In C", which also includes lots of (C I'm afraid) code. The book is about writing compiler-compiler type tools, so must cover generation, though it's a few years since I've read it.

Answer (score 0):

The comp.compilers usenet group came through with a bit of information I needed. Instead of "statemachine optimization" I needed to give google "statemachine reduction" or "statemachine minimization".